# how to print compelete data of jtable in java

Tags: java, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, messageformat

```
 MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("MEHBOOB RCIE MILL  ");
           MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("TEST");
        try {
            jTableReport.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
        } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e) {
            System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }
```

i have done this for print the data on printer when data is one page it work fine but when data increase means 3 or 5 page it print exception 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getJustificationInfos(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:988)
    at java.awt.font.TextLine.getJustifiedLine(TextLine.java:1358)
    at java.awt.font.TextLayout.getJustifiedLayout(TextLayout.java:817)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawString(SwingUtilities2.java:518)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(SwingUtilities2.java:612)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paintText(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:340)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paintText(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:319)`enter code here`
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paintText(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:410)
```

Comment: I was able to print a long table (6 pages) using this `print()` API. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: tblPurchase.setFont(new Font("Sakkal Majalla",Font.BOLD,20)); when i use this line then exception accrue and if use  tblPurchase.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16));  then it work ok . feeling confused